# Configuring Sendmail on Ubuntu Server + WordPress

Tags: wordpress, apache2, ubuntu

I am setting up multiple WordPress websites(each configured on it's own virtual host) setup on an Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS server with Apache2. I was trying to use a form app and found that the emails on WordPress do not work. So I installed sendmail as apparently WordPress relies primarly on sendmail.

However I'm unable to make it work. When I launch sendmailconfig, at one point I get:

```
Informational: ALIAS_FILE file empty: /etc/mail/aliases
Updating /etc/mail/aliases...
WARNING: local host name (ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-3) is not qualified; see cf/README: WHO AM I?
/etc/mail/aliases: 0 aliases, longest 0 bytes, 0 bytes total
```

also, when I try to send an email, it hangs. This is my `/etc/hosts` file:

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.debian.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
#
127.0.1.1 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-3 ubuntu-2gb-fsn1-3
127.0.0.1 localhost www.2.example

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

where `www.2.example`, is my second website.
The `/etc/hostname` file contains only the website URL `www.2.example`
I tried some modifications to these files but without success. I couldn't find good infos on sendmail. How should I configure this?

Comment: Sendmail can be provided by several different mail transfer agent (MTA) packages. By default Ubuntu uses exim4. You'll want to set up that package.

Comment: You definately don't want to be using the original Sendmail as it is painful.   Postfix is a drop in replacement for it with excellent support and a lot easier to configure (which is different to easy to configure) if you don't want to use exim4.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller So in the end I managed to install postfix. I tried exim4 before that and couldn't manage to make it work. Neither postfix worked in the first place. The overall problem in the end was banally my provider (Hetzner) blocking mail ports. Since I am running a VPS I didn't think they were blocking them, I was thinking that was managed only through the server distribution. Then I found the option to unblock the ports in Hetzner's control panel. Took me some time to find that. Thank you for the help.